# Search for text with Selenium no ID no Name

Tags: python, selenium

How am I able to find the following text (that has no ID, no Name or reference) using selenium/ python from the html code below.
the above mentioned text only appears after a certain condition has been met (file uploaded successfully)
See below part html code, this text is located between 2 tables, full code in [link provided](https://pastebin.com/8pe7C6V1)

**desired text I am looking for:**

> PCA Submit Request completed successfully

**Part html code:**

```
<TABLE border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=3>
<TR>
  <TD class=label width=20%>Contract Number:</TD>
  <TD width=25% class=fieldlabel>20003171</TD>
  <TD class=label width=20%>Separable Portion:</TD>
  <TD width=25% class=fieldlabel>30071948</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
  <TD class=label>Work Order:</TD>
  <TD class=fieldlabel>1</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
  <TD class=label>Title:</TD>
  <TD class=fieldlabel colspan=3>(NSW) Parramatta - Main Distribution Board LCR Automatic Transfer Switches Design & Construction P2 (PARZ) (IMC154) (44108)</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD class=label>Description:</TD>
  <TD class=fieldlabel colspan=3>(NSW) Parramatta - Main Distribution Board LCR Automatic Transfer Switches Design & Construction P2 (PARZ) (IMC154) (44108)</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD class=label>Issue No:</TD>
  <TD class=fieldlabel>2</TD>
  <TD class=label>Status:</TD>
  <TD class=fieldLabel>
    Project Approved</TD>
</TR>


</TABLE>
<!-- Divya : PBI000001666517 - 22Jun2017 release -->


  </TD>
 </TR>
 </TABLE>
 </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>


    <BR>
    <font color=blue>PCA Submit Request completed successfully.</font>



<P align=left>


<TABLE class="table" border=0 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=0 width="100%">

<TR>
  <TD class="colHeader" colspan=5>Documents associated with the PCA </TD>
  <TD class="cell" align="left" valign="center" colspan=3></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
  <TD class="colHeader">Reference</TD>
  <TD class="colHeader">Title</TD>
  <TD class="colHeader">File Type</TD>
  <TD class="colHeader">Issue No</TD>
  <TD class="colHeader">Size(Bytes)</TD>
  <TD class="colHeader">Date Registered</TD>
  <TD class="colHeader">Registered By</TD>
  <TD class="colHeader">View</TD>
</TR>



<TR class="cell">
  <TD class="cell">CSS-1528090864510</TD>
  <TD class="cell">PCA Documentation</TD>
  <TD class="cell">DOCX</TD>
  <TD class="cell">1</TD>
  <TD class="cell">97904</TD>
  <TD class="cell">04/06/2018</TD>
  <TD class="cell">ADMIN USER</TD>
  <TD valign="center" nowrap>
   <A HREF="javascript:showDocument('40437320', 'CSS-1528090864510')"><P ALIGN=CENTER><IMG SRC='/global/res/images/attach.gif' width=16 height=16 ALT='97904 Bytes' BORDER=0><br>CSS-1528090864510.DOCX</P></A></TD>

</TR>

</TABLE>
```

Comment: try /font[@color=blue]. It's a xPath

Comment: You can use implicit waits.

Comment: Invalid _HTML_, only one `<TABLE>` starting tag while 3  `</TABLE>` ending tags

Comment: paste link updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate your element using this:

```
//font[contains(text(),'PCA Submit Request completed successfully')]
```

Before this element appears, you can set a pause like in the example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.xPath, "xPath_to_element"))
)
```

or

```
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Comment: like this: text_confirmation =  wait(driver, 60).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("font[contains(text(),'PCA Submit Request completed successfully.')]").text)
           print text_confirmation

Comment: Something like this

Comment: please what is the xpath for:  <br>Change of Status completed successfully.

Comment: Hi Ossama, you can try this `//br[contains(text(),'Change of Status completed successfully')]`. If it won't work, please provide a HTML block with this element

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this **xpath** :

```
//font[text()='PCA Submit Request completed successfully.']
```

**OR**

```
//font[contains(text(),'PCA Submit Request completed successfully.')]
```

As you have mentioned , certain condition has to meet for that you can try **explicit wait** or `thread.sleep(time for waiting)` in **JAVA** and `time.sleep(5)` in **Python**  which is nothing but worst case of **Explicit wait**.